# How can I set the dynamic height of react-data-grid

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I have integrated react-data-grid into one of my projects. Over there I want to set the dynamic height of the grid based on the loaded rows. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```js
const dynamicHeight = Math.min(data.length * 6 + 10, 80) + 'vh'

return(
    <DataGrid style={{height = dynamicHeight}} />
)
```

- data.length is the number of rows
- 6vh is my row size
- 10vh is the necessary space to show the first row
- 80vh is my table max size

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper component around react-data-grid where you will calculate `dynamic height` taking into account whatever parameter you have. In my case, i took into account `rowHeight` & `visibleRowCount`. Once, you have calculated `dynamic Height`, you can pass it to `React-data-grid` using `minHeight` prop.

Example:

```
<ReactDataGrid
minHeight={dynamicHeight}
...
/>
```

Documentation Link: https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/docs/ReactDataGrid#minheight

Comment: Support for dynamic height appears to have been dropped in the canary release

Comment: This Data Grid makes me cry :(((

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `style` property and pass it a state variable `dynamicHeight` like so:

```
let [dynamicHeight, setDynamicHeight] = useState(*default height*);
```

When you want to change the height, you can call the function:

```
setDynamicHeight(*calculate your desired height here*)

return(
    <DataGrid style={{height = dynamicHeight}} />
)
```

I found this by searching the issues section on GitHub: https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/2553